# COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used vb.net

Tags: vb.net, com

Is it possible to reuse the com object that I just released with: Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)

When ever I try the following:

```
dim obj as ObjectType = New ObjectType
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
obj = nothing
obj = New ObjectType
```

I get the error: **COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.**

Why do I want to do this?
- I got the periphery (Xenta payment terminal) that is connected with a com-port & I use a com object to talk with it.
- I want to reinitialize the object without restarting the program. A normal: obj = nothing doesn't work. When I try to start the payment I get the following exception:
**The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))**

I was wondering if there was any possibility that I can do that?
Or any other suggestions on how to reinitialize my object?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not normal, you are just working with a COM server that hasn't been written very well.  This is not unusual for devices like this.  In fact, it looks to me like it was already written in .NET.  Use a disassembler to gain more insight.  You do need support from the manufacturer if that doesn't get you anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for this info :( I thought there was something wrong with the manufacturer. Because I have another com object in another program that is working perfectly. The manufacturer doesn't actually support this method anymore, but my boss refuses to buy the new DLL xD